# How to add patterns with rtMaven.deployer.deployArtifacts

Tags: maven, jenkins-pipeline, artifactory, jfrog-cli

I am using as below in Jenkins pipeline

```
def buildInfo = rtMaven.run pom: 'src/bwceapp.parent/pom.xml', goals: 'clean 
package initialize'
```

but this builds a lot of artifacts, I just want deploy with pattern i.e. only EAR,

`rtMaven.deployer.deployArtifacts  buildInfo` is deploying EAR along with lot of other artifacts such as dependency jars etc..

I could not find in the documentation how to use pattern in my approach, Any help is greatly appreciated.

tried this, `rtMaven.deployer.deployArtifacts buildInfo.addInclude("*.ear")` , but did not work.

And this did not work as well

```
rtMaven.deployer.artifactDeploymentPatterns.addInclude("*.ear") buildInfo
```

Comment: Why not using `mvn clean deploy` ?

Comment: My pipeline is integrated with artifactory so it could upload(deploy) the built artifacts to the artifactory. So I had to create an object rtMaven.

Comment: So this will be done by `mvn clean deploy` as well ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get it to working as below.

```
rtMaven.deployer.artifactDeploymentPatterns.addInclude("*.ear")

def buildInfo = rtMaven.run pom: 'src/bwceapp/pom.xml', goals: 'clean package initialize'

rtMaven.deployer.deployArtifacts  buildInfo
```